# What is the alternative to now?

Tags: solidity

I see many warnings against the use of `now` (`block.timestamp`) in solidity code but no one mentions any alternative of getting the time. What is the alternative of using `now`?

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with using `block.timestamp` is that it is manipulable by miners and random fluctuations to within an hour or so. For minute-scale time, you should use `block.number * 15`, which also can fluctuate but is less arbitrarily manipulable.

On the scale of days or more, `block.timestamp` will be far more accurate, since it is tied to real unix time.

Comment: can you explain why `block.number * 15`? are u assuming a block every 15 seconds?

Comment: Yes, on average. It's actually more like 14 now, but regardless it's actually random so you're not going to get great accuracy